# Outlook says "your profile is not configured" then closes immediately

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I had Outlook 2010 configured for an exchange email account that no longer works.  So I want to delete my configuration and start over.  However, when I start Outlook, I just get the following:

```
The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable.  Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.
[OK]
```

Then I get a Window to configure "Microsoft Exchange server" and "Mailbox" with button to [Check Name].  But when I click [Check name] I get

```
The name cannot be resolved.  The connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable.  Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action.
[OK]
```

So eventually I click [Cancel] and I get

```
Cannot open your default e-mail folders.  Your profile is not configured.
[OK]
```

Upon clicking [OK], Outlook closes.

All I want is the default configuration wizard that comes up when Outlook is new.  Is there any way to get back to the default configuration wizard?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to the `Control Panel` > `Mail` > `Show Profile` > delete the profile(s) in there, and click `Add` and it'll bring up the wizard.

Comment: You are the man.